# GET Facebook Page Post Video Source is not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am using Facebook Graph API, to get Page post.

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/357708837646769/posts?access_token=TOKEN&limit=25&fields=id,name,type,link,description,message,picture,source,from,created_time,object_id,shares,likes.limit(1).summary(true),full_picture

This API works fine. and returns value. 
However when I get a post type video, I try to fetch to Video Source using below API:

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/716404295377384/?access_token=TOKEN&fields=source
>   https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/716404295377384/?access_token=TOKEN&fields=source

Here is the Page post doc on Facebook

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/post

If we check the fields, for source it says:

**Name:** source

**Description:** A URL to any Flash movie or video file attached to the post.

**Type:** string

However, the API is not returning any value for "source" field. Tried with both 2.7 & 3.1 Graph API version. Also Facebook has not mentioned anywhere, that the "source" field is deprecated or won't be available in API.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

> Also Facebook has not mentioned anywhere, that the "source" field is deprecated or won't be available in API.

They mention the following change in the changelog for v2.12, 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.12#gapi-90-videos

> Page-owned videos — The `source` field will no longer be returned for Page-owned videos unless the User making the request has a role on the owning Page.

So, are you using the right kind of access token …?